# How to use the output of a javascript function to display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a mock website to practice using HTML, CSS and javascript. I want the user to be able to click on an image an overlay will appear and an appointment date will displayed on screen. When i try to display the output of the function nothing happens.

I have tried calling the function, the specific output var and just the "Date.prototype.getNextWeekDate" itself.

```
<script>
Date.prototype.getNextWeekDay = function(d) {
  if (d) {
    var next = this;
    next.setDate(this.getDate() - this.getDay() + 7 + d);
    return next;
  }
}

var now = new Date();
var nextMonday = now.getNextWeekDay(1); // 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ...
return nextMonday;  
</script>

<style>
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
</style>

<div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text">
    <p>Your appointment is at:<script>fucntion(d);</script></p>

  </div>
</div>


<script>
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>


<img src="images/m&R_Idk.jpg" width="500" height="298" alt="Mechanic Appointment"
       onClick="on()" >
```

This current date in 7 days should be outputted onto the overlay but nothing outputs at all.

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: The script in `p` element is executed a the parsing time of the page only, and most likely also throws an error (`fucntion is not defined`). Drop the script and assign the appointment date to the `textContent` property of the `p` element in the image's click handler function. And also remove the return statement form the body of the script.

Comment: Illegal return statement and Function statements require a function name

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant like this: nextMonday.textContent;
nextMonday.textContent = String

Comment: Nope, `nextMonday` is the date, as said, remove the return from the body of the script, and the script from `p`. `return` is allowed inside a function only. You need [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/ba3snzx1/) ...